# Logarithmic Liouville Theorem

Tags: complex-analysis

I am studying for a preliminary exam, and the following question has appeared on a previous exam:
Let $f$ be a holomorphic function on $\mathbb{C} \setminus \{ 0\}$. Suppose that for any $z \neq 0$, we have that 
$$ |f(z)| \leq |\log (|z|) |.$$
Show that $f(z) \equiv 0$.

I am a bit stuck on how to solve this question. Certainly it is a Liouville like theorem, so the proof should follow like Liouville's proof. To this end, there are a few ideas that might help:

i) We could look at $g(z) = f(1/z)$, which is well defined on $\mathbb{C} \setminus 0$. This doesn't seem too helpful, since $|\log(|z|)| \rightarrow \infty$ as $|z| \rightarrow \infty$ and $|z| \rightarrow 0$.

ii) Expanding $f$ in a power series at $0$ gives $f(z) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n z^n$, so we may use the fact that 
$$|a_n| \leq \frac{1}{2 \pi r^n} \int_0^{2\pi} |f(re^{i \theta})| d \theta.$$
Using the bound $|f(z)| \leq |\log (|z|) |$ could show that $a_n =0$ for any $n $, proving that $f(z) \equiv 0$.

I think that the second approach is more promising than the first, but I still need some help putting it all together. Any assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: How can you expand $f$ is a power series at $0$ if it in not necessarily holomorphic at $0$?

Comment: Shoot, you're right. I'd need to expand it in a Laurent series instead to make this idea work.

Comment: The idea of proving it like Liouville is a good one. Hint: Expand in a Laurent series and look at the formula for the coefficients.

Comment: There is another way to prove this: The assumption implies that $f(z)=0$ for $|z|=1$, then the uniqueness principle implies that $f \equiv 0$.

Comment: Thanks for the help! Using the uniqueness theorem is a clever way to prove this.

Comment: @LukasGeyer: That is much more elegant! Please post it as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Proving it like Liouville (showing that all Laurent series coefficients are zero) or Riemann's theorem on removable singularities would be the standard way, and quite flexible for slight variations in the assumptions. Here there is another way, too: By assumption, $f(z)=0$ for $|z|=1$, so the set of zeros of $f$ contains the whole unit circle. By the uniqueness principle this implies that $f \equiv 0$.

Answer (score 1):

We have
$$
 |z f(z) | \le |z| \cdot |\log |z|| \implies \lim_{z \to 0} z f(z) = 0
$$
and [Riemann's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Removable_singularity#Riemann's_theorem)  implies that $f$ has a *removable singularity* at $z=0$.

The same argument can be applied to $g(z) = f(1/z)$ to show that $f$ has a removable singularity at $z = \infty$.

So $f$ is (the restriction of) an entire function with a finite limit at  $z = \infty$, and now you can apply Liouville's theorem to conclude that $f$ is constant.

Setting $z=1$ then shows that $f$ is identically zero.